# How to check if the username existed in the User table of the database or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to develop a simple user management system for the admin of the web application. I am using ASP.NET Wizard Control for this task.
I just put a TextBox for writing the username and when the admin clicks on the Next button, the system should check if the username existed in the database or not. If it is existed, the system should display his information in a placeholder for the admin.

I am struggling with this task. I did the following in the code-behind:

```
//For checking the user
if (Request.QueryString["Username"] != null)
{
    String strUserName = Request.QueryString["Username"];

    //Check userName Here
    String strReturnStatus = "false";

    if (CheckUsername(Request.QueryString["Username"]) == true)
    {
        strReturnStatus = "true";
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(strReturnStatus);
    Response.End();
}
```

Now, I think to create a second method called CheckUsername which I don't know what I should put it inside it:

```
private bool CheckUsername(string p)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

It may seem that this question is simple or stupid, but I am a new developer and I could not be able to find a simple resource that could help me in this issue particularly.

Comment: FYI, there is no need to prefix your titles with things like "ASP.NET: ". That's what the tags are for.

Comment: You have to write a simple select statement that queries the database for your username, that being said, without knowing what you are using to communicate with your db or the type of db (SQL, MYSQL, etc..) it is hard to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following method is what you're after:

```
private bool CheckUsername(string username)
{
    string connString = "";
    string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username = @username";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
         conn.Open(); // Open DB connection.

         using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)); // Add the SQL parameter.

             int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

             // True (> 0) when the username exists, false (= 0) when the username does not exist.
             return (count > 0);
         }
    }
}
```

You can fill in the blanks (e.g specify a connection string `connString` and modify `cmdText`). The SQL query I specified in `cmdText` is under the assumption of a typical user management system where you have common table names and columns; `Users` (table) and `Username` (column). It's hard to justify as you haven't specified the structure. Modify it to suit your applications needs.

The method of counting how many records exist is quite common in most cases. I frequently use that method of checking/validating things as I see fit.

Further information about the code (classes) I used in my example above:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx

I also advise you read about data access (not that link). I'll leave you to that.

Answer (score 0):

I adjust some point in your code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Username"]))
{
    ---
    ---

    if (CheckUsername(Request.QueryString["Username"]))
    {
        ---
     ---
}
```

Refer to this link as tutorial for your task: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx